# Выбор определенного элемента из текста

Tags: python, python-2.7, работа-с-текстом

Есть текствой файл `stat.log` вида :

```
 abcb & abcb: 00 40 00 00 00 , pwstatus: 00 00 00 00 00 
 bus0 e1, e0 40, 56 (60, 75) v1 0,84 v2 6.5 v3 15.3
 bus1 e1, e0 20, 40 (60, 75) v1 0,7 v2 4.2 v3 12.3
 bus1 e1, e0 20, 40 (60, 75) v1 0,7 v2 4.2 v3 12.3
 bus2 e1, e0 20, 40 (60, 75) v1 0,7 v2 4.2 v3 12.3
 bus2 e1, e0 20, 40 (60, 75) v1 0,7 v2 4.2 v3 12.3
```

Как с помощью Python 2.7 присвоить переменной `temp` значение 5-го столбца во второй строке (`56`), ну, или вообще, как задавать переменным значение любого столбца любой строки такого вида?

Comment: 1. Открыть файл. 2. Читать по одной строчке пока не дойдёте до нужной по счёту. 3. Нужную строку методом split разбить по символу табуляции. 4. Из получившегося списка по индексу взять нужный столбец.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
with open("stat.log") as stat:
    stat.readline()             # Пропуск первой строки
    line2 = stat.readline()     # Вторая строка

items = line2.split(", ")       # Разбитие на элементы
item3 = items[2]                # 3-й элемент списка (так как 1-й: items[0])
temp = item3[0:2]               # Первые 2 знаки

print temp                      # Только тест
```

Вывод:

> `56`